# Why command \dt gives - no relations found?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a database in postgres. It has 3 empty tables. The table has user `tom` as its `Superuser` along with `root`. I am logged in as `tom` and connected to `mydb` database. But still the commands `\d` or `\dt` - gives `no relations found`.

Is there any alternate to `SHOW TABLE` in postgresql?

Could not find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229211/postgresql-no-relations-found)

I get results from - `\dt *.*`.

Comment: If `\dt *.*` works but `\dt` doesn't, then the tables' schema is probably not in your [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951875/postgresql-how-do-i-set-the-search-path-at-the-user-level

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It is not a problem with your `search_path`, it could be an issue with your schema permissions as described [in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7758860/1959278). Check with `\dn+` that the `public` schema indicates permissions for the `postgres` role, and if not, grant them with: `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public;`

Answer (score 18):

I solved my problem by using double quote e.g \d "Table_name". Because my table name is capitalized like Foo, Bar. Hope that could help someones.

Comment: the pain of quotes :(

Answer (score 13):

You might not be connected to the right database.

The first command `\c DATABASE_NAME`, coming from the following [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/9dzgz7/ds_did_not_find_any_relation_named_xyz/) on Reddit, did the trick for me.

> Make sure you're connected to the correct database with \c . Using \l will list all databases regardless of which database you're connected to, but most commands are specific to the connected database.

> Use \dt *.** to list all tables with name matching  in all schemas.

> Assuming the table exists, it will tell you what schema it's in. Then you can query with SELECT * FROM .;.

> If you want to avoid having to explicitly specify the schema name, make sure the schema that contains the table is in your path: SHOW search_path and SET search_path .

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. None of the answers above helped. I was able to see my table when I ran `\dt .*`. Then I realized I had to call explicitly state its schema when running SELECT statements.

So, if you run `SELECT * FROM public.<your_tablename_goes_here>;` it should work. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have different instances of postgres running on server on different port it helps when you connect to database with specific port psql -p 5432 databasename( or psql -p 5433 databasename etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you must have not added a semicolon at the end that's what always happens to me I always forget my semicolon -> create table nameoftable()

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me when I removed the default privileges for `PUBLIC` on the `public` schema (specifically the `USAGE` privilege).

Answer (score 0):

For me , the particular schema wasn't present in the `search_path` .
After adding it to the search_path , it got fixed